# Parse log file with PHP // Show lines with numbers

Tags: php

I have an odd script that exports data to a log file, the file looks like this:

```
contactid: 
15186 is present in PND!. contactid: 15186
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
PND Done contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
3630 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3630
contactid: 
contactid: 
3679 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3679
3695 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3695
3699 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3699
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
3761 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3761
contactid: 
3767 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3767
3770 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3770
3772 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3772
contactid: 
3785 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3785
contactid: 
contactid:
```

I've written a script that removes leading `contactid:` text:

```
$file1 = $_GET['id'].".log";
$lines = file($file1);  
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
{
    $int = trim($line, "contactid: <br/>");
    echo $int;
}
```

I can then open the file in browser which returns data like this:

```
15186 is present in PND!. contactid: 15186
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
PND Done contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
3630 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3630
contactid: 
contactid: 
3679 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3679
3695 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3695
3699 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3699
contactid: 
contactid: 
contactid: 
3761 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3761
contactid: 
3767 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3767
3770 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3770
3772 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3772
contactid: 
3785 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3785
contactid: 
contactid:
```

What I'm trying to do is remove all empty contactid: rows so my output looks like this:

```
15186 is present in PND!. contactid: 15186
3630 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3630
3679 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3679
3695 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3695
3699 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3699
3761 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3761
3767 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3767
3770 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3770
3772 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3772
3785 Is present in PMF!. contactid: 3785
```

Stripping down this data has thrown me for a twist! Any help or tips on getting this to work would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first load the file using [`file()`](http://php.net/file) with the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag to ignore new lines. Then, strip off the whitespace from the beginning and end of the line using [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) and then print the line if the whole line is **not equal to** `contactid:`.

```
$lines = file($file1, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);  
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
{
    if (trim($line) !== 'contactid:') {
        echo $line.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Using a regular expression might be easier in this case:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.txt');
echo preg_replace('/(contactid:\s*)/', '', $content);
```

Regex autopsy:

- `()` - indicates a capturing group
- `contactid:` - matches the characters `contactid:` literally
- `\s*` - matches any white space character zero or more times

The statement means: replace everything that matches `contactid:<whitespace>` with `''`.

Comment: Amal, the regular expression seems to get me a lot closer, all of the lines that are just contactid: are not displayed but there is a blank empty line where a contactid: would be.

Answer (score 0):

Using Amal's code I came up with this that gives me the results I want, but are their ways I can clean up the code by combining the preg_replace():

```
$content = file_get_contents($file1, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$str = preg_replace('/(contactid: <br\/>\s*)/', '', $content);
$str2 = preg_replace('/(PND Done\s*)/', 'PND Done <br/>', $str);
echo preg_replace('/(PMF Done\s*)/', 'PMF Done <br/>', $str2);
```

But it is giving me the output I've been looking for...

Thanks!